# What does \% and \\ mean in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I know the meaning of `%` and `_` wildcard characters ,but i was stuck in a question which was using the two additional characters `\%` and `\\`,i was not able to understand what these characters actually mean in the `SQL` query

```
SELECT productID 
FROM productList 
WHERE productName LIKE 'ab\%cd%'
```

and

```
SELECT productID 
FROM productList 
WHERE productName LIKE 'ab\\cd%'
```

are these two same things or different ??

Comment: This is a MySQL specific behavior, so I have removed the <sql> tag, since that is for ANSI SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `%` is a special character, you have to escape it with a `\` to match a literal `%` symbol in your data. So, `'ab\%cd%'` matches the letter a, followed by the letter b, followed by a % symbol, the letter c, the letter d, then any other text (because the last `%` is a wildcard).

Similarly, since `\` is a special character used to create escape sequences, you have to escape it to match a literal `\` in a pattern, so to match a single `\` you have to encode it as `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to see the difference is by example.

To better understand it you will need knowledge about 3 things when using `LIKE` operator in SQL:

- `\` is used to escape special characters to use them as normal chars
- `%` is used to match any number of characters (including 0)
- special characters are `\` and `%` so if you want to include them literally you need to escape them, so to check for them in text column you respectively need to use `\\` and `\%`.

Below is a table with words and true/false results for `LIKE` comparison with both patterns:

```
   word   | ab\%cd% | ab\\cd%
----------+---------+---------
 ab\      | f       | f        -- this would match second pattern but there is no "cd" at the end
 ab\cd    | f       | t        -- \\ is escaped "\", and % matches none characters
 ab\cdxzy | f       | t        -- \\ is escaped "\", and % matches character sequence "xzy"
 abcd     | f       | f        -- every string requires either "%" or "\" character after "ab"
 ab%cd    | t       | f        -- \% is escaped "%", and % matches none characters
 ab%cdxzy | t       | f        -- \% is escaped "%", and % matches character sequence "xzy"
 ab\%cd   | f       | f        -- there is no pattern which matches both chars "\%" in sequence
 ab%\cd   | f       | f        -- same as above, but characters are "%\" in sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

> The `\%` and `\_` sequences are used to search for literal instances
>   of `%` and `_` in pattern-matching contexts where they would otherwise
>   be interpreted as wildcard characters.

For `\\` it searches for a single back slash `\`.

Ref: [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual, 9.1.1 String Literals, Table 9.1 Special Character Escape Sequences](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html)